# Binding JSON string to dropdownlist

Tags: json, dropdown

My drop-down list id is 'DropdownList'

My json string is in this form :

```
[{"Domain":"domain"}]
```

How can I bind the JsonString to the dropdownlist?

Comment: please be more specific.

Answer (score 4):

So going ahead with some dummy data, here what you can be doing is - Have a `JSON` in a file named `data.json` as :

```
data = '[{"Mode":"CARD"}, {"Mode":"CASH"}, {"Mode":"CHEQUE"}]';
```

Add the `src` tag to your `HTML` so it knows where to find the `JSON` from :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
```

And then have the following function in your `JavaScript` -

```
function addOptions(){
        var jsonArray = JSON.parse(data);
        var select = document.getElementById('DropdownList');
        var option;
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
          option = document.createElement('option');
          option.text = jsonArray[i]["Mode"];
          select.add(option);
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you could also have the same function above, in your `HTML` itself, under the `Script` tag. In which case, your `HTML` up till now would look something like -

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
<script>
    function addOptions(){
        var jsonArray = JSON.parse(data);
        var select = document.getElementById('DropdownList');
        var option;
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
          option = document.createElement('option');
          option.text = jsonArray[i]["Mode"];
          select.add(option);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now you can chose when you want to call this function. When the form is loaded or whichever other even you wish to call it on. Assuming you want to call it when the form is loaded, go on and put the following in your `HTML` -

```
<body onload="addOptions();">
    <select id="dd"></select>
</body>
```

So, your overall and final `HTML` would look like -

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
<script>
    function addOptions(){
        var jsonArray = JSON.parse(data);
        var select = document.getElementById('DropdownList');
        var option;
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
          option = document.createElement('option');
          option.text = jsonArray[i]["Mode"];
          select.add(option);
        }
    }
</script>
<body onload="addOptions();">
    <select id="dd"></select>
</body>
```

**Alternatively**, if you had a server resource that returned the following : 
**/myjson** then you could use `AJAX` to overcome the same too -

```
[
{
    "Mode": "CARD"
},
{
    "Mode": "CASH"
},
{
    "Mode": "CHEQUE"
}
```

]

Then create the  elements using `JavaScript`.

```
$.ajax({
url:'/myjson',
type:'GET',
dataType: 'json',
success: function( json ) {
    $.each(json, function(i, value) {
        $('#myid').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value.Mode));
    });
}
```

});

This solution would mostly work on modern browsers, unless you're running `Internet Explorer`. If you're running `Internet Explorer`, follow this thread -
[How to display JSON objects as options of a dropdown in HTML, using a common JavaScript funciton for all objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608609/how-to-display-json-objects-as-options-of-a-dropdown-in-html-using-a-common-jav)

The jsfiddle will also help you have a better understanding :)
Hope this helps.